# How do I calculate confidence intervals for I-squared in order to assess heterogeneity between two pooled studies?

Tags: confidence-interval, meta-analysis, small-sample, heterogeneity

I am conducting a meta analysis and for some of my pooled data, there are only two studies available. Based on this [publication](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4410499/) I have been calculating confidence intervals around I-squared in order to assess heterogeneity. I've used the equation provided in chapter 16 of Introduction to Meta-analysis (Borenstein, Hedges, & Higgins, 2011) page 124 and also described [here](http://psych.colorado.edu/~willcutt/pdfs/Higgins_2002.pdf).

Part of the calculation is obtaining B or SE[In(H)] then using this value to calculate the confidence intervals around I-squared. Two different calculations are used depending on whether Q > df+1 or Q =< df+1.

[image]

In my case, when I have calculated Q for pooled data with only two studies, Q is always below df+1 and therefore I've had to use equation 16.21. The problem is that this always leads to an error as the df is 1, and if you input this into equation 16.21 is it inevitably asking to divide 1 by 0, which leads to the error.

I've double checked my Q calculation and compared my output to the output I got from Comprehensive Meta-analysis, which were the same.
I have been able to successfully calculate CI around I-squared for all other pooled data when the number of pooled studies is more than 2.

Am I missing something? Heterogeneity was already low for the two studies (I-squared=0%) so does that mean it does not theoretically make sense to calculate CI for I-squared when there are only two studies with low heterogeneity? Is there a better way to calculate heterogeneity with only two studies?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not using percentile bootstrap?

Comment: From my understanding, with only two studies, you can only calculate the I2. You need three or more to calculate the uncertainty intervals (CIs around the I2). Borenstein has an Excel workbook that I found online that shows the calculations.

Comment: I am not sure  whether we should and can calculate CI for I-squared when individually for studies these statistics are not available. Even if this statistics is available for each study,  what purpose a meta-analytic  confidence interval shall serve ?  Further, two studies and "small samples" appear to be innocuous for inference !

Answer (score 1):

You could try using confidence intervals established using the Q-profile method outlined by Viechtbauer in his 2007 paper "Confidence intervals for the amount of heterogeneity in meta-analysis" available [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/sim.2514) and used in his R package metafor. I have just tried a toy example with $I^2=0$ and two studies and got confidence intervals.